# Is there a way to be notified when an ICommand is executed?

Tags: c#, icommand

Here is my code:

```
var viewModel = factory.Create();
var commandBinding = new CommandBinding(viewModel.Command, (target, e) => {
                                                                              // Not called?
                                                                          });
```

Not sure if I can use CommandBinding like that (as it's not working, the response must surely be 'no' :-D).

So my question is, how can I be notified that the viewModel.Command.Execute() method was executed? (viewModel.Command  is an ICommand btw)

I could add something to the viewModel to handle it but... I'm sure I'm missing something.
Thanks for the help

Comment: [`CanExecuteChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.icommand.canexecutechanged?view=netcore-3.1)?

Comment: No, don't want to be notified when the canexecutechanged but when the command was executed

Comment: Perhaps use an observer pattern? Or what do you mean "notified".

Comment: Sounds like [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/299295). What is X problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Did you implement `ICommand` yourself? Then just add an event, that is invoked when the command is executed.